# SQL Count Records by Columns (Data Points)

Tags: sql-server, count

I am pretty familiar with the COUNT function in SQL, but I don't know how to use it to achieve the results I'm looking for.

I manage a data warehouse with routine loads and I would like to report the number of raw data points (defined by #records * #columns) each time I load records into a table.

I can use the COUNT function to get the #records in the formula, but how can I dynamically count columns in a table? From there I can do the math.

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to use Dynamic-SQL because columns cannot be parameterised in SQL. You'll want to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the schema tables where table meta data is stored in sql server.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
```